# Setting up Codeigniter HMVC with tank auth

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, tankauth

I am having trouble getting a working Codeigniter version 2.0.3 with hmvc and tank auth(set up as a module) setup properly. I have installed CI properlly and then install HMVC with these directions https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

I get to my welcome controller/view as example just fine which means the HMVC is working. Next I try to add tank auth to the project by adding it to a folder in the modules folder. It has the proper controller/view/model etc.. setup within the tank auth. I even added in routes something like

$route["auth"]="auth/login";

I also extended the controller within the auth module to MX_Controller like as directed. Also in the constructor I have :

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('security'); <--failing to load this

    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
     $this->form_validation->CI =& $this;
```

It seems to be redirecting fine to the module however it comes up with an error saying ::

An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested class: security

What am I doing wrong? Does any one have a working CI installation with HMVC and tank auth as a module so I can see how its done? I'm new to HMVC, thanks

Comment: Does the file security.php exist in the library-folder?

Comment: the security.php is part of codeigniter itself so it is not located in the modules/auth/libraries/... folder. Do i have to grab the instance of CI in order to call its libraries/helpers within constructor of a modules controller?

Comment: So I changed $this->load->library('security'); to $this->load->helper('security'); and now a new error occurs , I think when it tries to load tank_auth library, saying that the configuration file tank_auth.php can not be found..although there is  modules/modulename/config/tank_auth.php intact. Not sure why its finding it but I'm assuming it simliar to my other problems

Comment: There are different kinds of security-files in CodeIgniter, one of them is a helper, and the other one is used to escape data on submission to the database.

Comment: well the original tank auth calls for the library security not the helper, tank auth only uses CI's native security library and doesn't supply its own

Comment: not sure whys its NOT finding it , ment to say in previous post but was too late to edit it

Comment: If you creates a new module, with a controller in it and only load the security-library - do you get the same error?

Comment: yes, just tried with with a module that only included a controller with a call : $this->load->library('security'); and I get same error as before but if i change it to $this->load->helper('security') it works fine. This is a fresh install of codeigniter so I didnt remove any original libraries/helpers etc..

Comment: What happens if you put a new controller within your original controller-folder? (Not within a module) and try the same thing? Might be some setting within HMVC that messes things up.

Comment: still dont understand why it can't find the auth_tank config file though

Comment: If i create a normal controller (not module) and try to load library it says same error.

Comment: I'd suggest you redownload and reinstall codeigniter from scratch and at each step you do - try to debug and test everything (especially $this->load->library('security')). When you find the source of the problem it's much easier to find how to solve it.

Comment: I'm using another copy of the same installation just without the HMVC and tank auth is calling security library just fine...so what else could it be?

Comment: i have redone ci reinstall and hmv step by step and am getting same error w tank auth..why did the hmvc developer even bother making it w o documentation...stupid. im done being frustrated..giving up on hmvc

Comment: any one have a ci install w tank auth running through hmvc? i have followed the directions andam lost

Comment: I have tried to set up hmvc and CI 2.0.3 and made a simple module with just a controller to try to load the security library and im running into the same problem. this is without trying to install tank auth. I followed the directions perfect for both hvmc installation and CI. Is it possible to zip up the files so someone can look at what im doing? it wouldn't be practical to try to copy and paste everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the same problem, but i solved by simple adding a comment to the

```
$this->load->library('security');
```

so it will look like this:

```
//$this->load->library('security');
```

since security its now part of the codeigniter core, i guess its already loaded by default, and everything seems to be working pretty good

Comment: try this :  $this->load->helper('security');

Comment: and replace `$this->security->xss_clean();` to `xss_clean();

Answer (score 4):

it is in Helper now according to [CodeIgniter 3.0 user guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/security_helper.html)

try:

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

Comment: so you mean this is helper not library

Answer (score 2):

I fix this, by creating `Security.php` file in `application/libraries` directory with the following code:

```
require_once(BASEPATH.'core/Security.php');

class Security extends CI_Security { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I simply took the security.php file from codeigniters system/core folder and dropped it into system/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

- move the file `security.php` from `system/core` to `system/libraries`
- then edit `core/codeigniter.php` line number 204 from `$SEC =& load_class('Security', 'core');` to `$SEC =& load_class('Security', 'libraries');`

Answer (score 0):

Security.php is present in "codeigniter/system/core/Security.php"
so provide this path your problem gets solved easily

```
load->library('../core/security');
```

Answer (score 0):

I Read CodeIgniter 3.X User Guide and I was found that "Security" is available as a 'helper' Now.

So you need to change this;

```
$this->load->library('security');
```

into

```
$this->load->helper('security');
```

**XSS Filtering**

The Input class has the ability to filter input automatically to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. If you want the filter to run automatically every time it encounters POST or COOKIE data you can enable it by opening your application/config/config.php file and setting this:

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

You need to read a CodeIgniter 3.0 User Guide there are so many changes and implementation or **please Refer change log.**